# Why does my SRGAN (using PyTorch) result look similar to SRResNet results?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, pytorch

SRGAN was implemented using PyTorch.

Generator pre-train was conducted in 100 times and the SRGAN train was conducted in 200 times.

The code is a combination of the existing github codes.

For the content loss, MSELoss () in PyTorch was used and BCELoss () in PyTorch was used for adversarial loss.

When I ran code, LossD converges to 0, and LossG oscillates around a certain value. So I stopped training because I thought it was not training anymore.

If the training is 1e5 as in the paper, will the result change? Or is it a matter of loss function?

Below is the SRGAN training code.

```
print('Adversarial training')
for epoch in range(NUM_EPOCHS):
    train_bar = tqdm(train_loader)
    running_results = {'batch_sizes': 0, 'd_loss': 0, 'g_loss': 0, 'd_score': 0, 'g_score': 0}
    # train_bar = tqdm(train_loader)
    for data, target in train_bar:
        batch_size = data.size(0)
        running_results['batch_sizes'] += batch_size

        target_real = Variable(torch.ones(batch_size, 1))
        target_fake = Variable(torch.zeros(batch_size, 1))

        if torch.cuda.is_available():
            target_real = target_real.cuda()
            target_fake = target_fake.cuda()

        real_img = Variable(target)
        z = Variable(data)

        # Generate real and fake inputs
        if torch.cuda.is_available():
            inputsD_real = real_img.cuda()
            inputsD_fake = netG(z.cuda())
        else:
            inputsD_real = real_img
            inputsD_fake = netG(z)

        ######### Train discriminator #########
        netD.zero_grad()

        # With real data
        outputs = netD(inputsD_real)
        D_real = outputs.data.mean()

        lossD_real = adversarial_criterion(outputs, target_real)

        # With fake data
        outputs = netD(inputsD_fake.detach()) # Don't need to compute gradients wrt weights of netG (for efficiency)
        D_fake = outputs.data.mean()

        lossD_fake = adversarial_criterion(outputs, target_fake)

        lossD_total = lossD_real + lossD_fake

        lossD_total.backward()

        # Update discriminator weights
        optimizerD.step()

        ######### Train generator #########
        netG.zero_grad()

        real_features = Variable(feature_extractor(inputsD_real).data)
        fake_features = feature_extractor(inputsD_fake)

        lossG_vgg19 = content_criterion(fake_features, real_features)
        lossG_adversarial = adversarial_criterion(netD(inputsD_fake).detach(), target_real)
        lossG_mse = content_criterion(inputsD_fake, inputsD_real)

        lossG_total = lossG_mse + 2e-6 * lossG_vgg19 + 0.001 * lossG_adversarial
        lossG_total.backward()

        # Update generator weights
        optimizerG.step()
```

Comment: GANs can be quite frickle to train and if you use a different learning rate or anything different at all than in the paper, all bets are off regarding its performance. Even if you use the same code as in the paper the result will still drastically vary from run to run, depending on the random seed.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the classic GAN model for alternate training, this situation is inevitable, try to change the training method